# SQL Extra data in the date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, union

I have a query with something as follow

```
Site_name  LOB date
Site 1    Sales 6/1
Site 1    Sales 6/2
...       ....  ..
Site 2    Sales 6/1
Site 2    Sales 6/2
...       ....  ..
Site 3    Consumer 6/1
Site 3    Consumer 6/1
```

in the data I would like to have all the dates MTD and an extra two rows in the date column. I would like this to contain 'MTD' and 'Target' so my resulting table would look something like this

```
 Site_name  LOB date
    Site 1    Sales 6/1
    Site 1    Sales 6/2
    ...       ....  ..
    Site 1    Sales Target
    Site 1    Sales MTY

    Site 2    Sales 6/1
    Site 2    Sales 6/2
    ...       ....  ..
    Site 2    Sales Target
    Site 2    Sales MTY

    Site 3    Consumer 6/1
    Site 3    Consumer 6/1
    ...       ....     ...
    Site 3    Consumer Target
    Site 3    Consumer MTD
```

My basic query for what I have now is there are some where's that I dont figure really matter here.

```
   Select Distinct 
    Site_name, LOB, Day_date 
   where month(day_date)>=month(getdate()-5)
   and year(day_date)=year(getdate())
```

Comment: In it's current form your question is unanswerable because there are nowhere near enough details posted. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: If you're asking how to insert rows into a table, then the answer is with an INSERT statement.   If you're asking something more than that, then you need to be more specific because your question is not at all clear.

Comment: How would you suppose to store strings in `Date` column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you want exactly this, but it might give you an idea. 
At least, it produces results exactly as you've requested:

```
;WITH tData(Site,LOB) as (SELECT 'Site 1','Sales' UNION ALL SELECT 'Site 2','Sales' UNION ALL SELECT 'Site 3','Consumer' ),
tDate(sDate) as (SELECT CAST('2016-06-01' as Date) UNION ALL SELECT '2016-06-02'),
DateCol(sDate,sOrder) as (SELECT CAST(sDate as VARCHAR), 0 FROM tDate UNION ALL SELECT 'Target', 1 UNION ALL SELECT 'MTD', 2)
SELECT tData.*, sDate as [Date]
FROM tData, DateCol
ORDER BY Site, sOrder, sDate

Site    LOB         Date
Site 1  Sales       2016-06-01
Site 1  Sales       2016-06-02
Site 1  Sales       Target
Site 1  Sales       MTD
Site 2  Sales       2016-06-01
Site 2  Sales       2016-06-02
Site 2  Sales       Target
Site 2  Sales       MTD
Site 3  Consumer    2016-06-01
Site 3  Consumer    2016-06-02
Site 3  Consumer    Target
Site 3  Consumer    MTD
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. I had to modify the query a bit but that gave me the basic thing I needed to make it work